# Spring cannot print system properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>



        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

File `FooController.java`

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController("foo")
public class FooController {

    @Value("#{systemEnvironment['JAVA_HOME']}")
    String javaHome;

    @Value("$(systemProperties.monthly.text)")
    String string2;

    @Value("#{systemProperties['monthly.text']}")
    String string3;

    @GetMapping("/bar")
    String foo(){
        System.out.println("string2 = " + string2);
        System.out.println("string3 = " + string3);
        return javaHome;
    }

}

// http://localhost:8080/bar
// D:\tools\graalvm-jdk-20.0.1+9.1
```

This is my full project https://github.com/donhuvy/spring-boot3-system-properties/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/demo/FooController.java#L13 .

I want print system properties in 2 ways. Please help me `monthly.text`

Comment: `$(` is the wrong start for a value expression you must use curly braces. Also `-montly.text` is the wrong way of providing system. properties they must be prefixed with `-D`. `-Dmontly.text=foo`.

Comment: System properties are part of the `Environment` so you can just use `@Value("${monthly.text}")`. Do you have to use a SpEL expression for some reason?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson it is a question in interview more than a reality case (must choose 2 ways). In the past, I used SpEL in Thymeleaf view, even I also used SpEL in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['monthly.text']}")
String string2;
```

And set the JVM arguments:

```
-Dmonthly.text=love
```

Part of the difficulty is that the name of the property includes a period. If you have control over the name of the property, I would get rid of the period. Then it becomes simpler:

```
@Value("${monthly_text}") String param
```

And of course:

```
-Dmonthly_text=love
```